# How to create a "Pear-like" shape with css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want to create this shape with css.

[image]

I have tried using border-radius but i can't make it exactly like above.

This is the closest i could come up with the border-radius property
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7ohf2Lk/13/)

```css
.mybox {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #7158FB, #925FE0);
  width: 245px;
  height: 320px;
  border-top-left-radius: 60% 75%;
  border-top-right-radius: 60% 75%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 30%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox"></div>
```

Comment: [you could use this nice little tool](https://9elements.github.io/fancy-border-radius/) :)

Comment: @VilleKoo Whoa! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it using 2 different elements and you will have a better rendring:

```css
.box {
  width: 245px;
  height: 320px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#7158FB, #925FE0);
  z-index:-1;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  height: 180%;
  right: -16.5%;
  left: -16.5%;
  background-size:100% 32.5%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 42%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 80%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 80%;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[image: Pear shape CSS]

For a random gradient you have to adjust the code like below:

```css
.box {
  --h:320px;
  width: 245px;
  height: var(--h);
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-image:linear-gradient(30deg,red,green,blue);
  z-index:-1;
}

.box:before {
  top: 0;
  height: calc(var(--h) * 1.8);
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-bottom:calc((1.8 - 1 + 0.42) * var(--h));
  right: -16.5%;
  left: -16.5%;
  background-size:100% calc(100%/1.8);
  background-clip:content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 50% 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50% 100%;
}

.box:after {
  bottom: 0;
  height: calc(var(--h) * 0.42);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 80%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 80%;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px 25px;
  background-size:100% calc(100%/0.42);
  background-position:bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

[image: Pear shape CSS]

Answer (score 3):

try using `border-radius`

```css
.mybox {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #7158FB, #925FE0);
  width: 245px;
  height: 320px;
  border-radius: 48% 52% 50% 50% / 69% 68% 32% 31%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is pretty close but as i see it it's not exactly right. I think what is not achievable with just `border-radius` property